# Change ActiveX Control Textbox color Based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have three Form Controls option buttons linked to a cell, lets say A1. When optionbutton1 is selected A1 = 1, when optionbutton2 is selected A1 = 2, and when optionbutton3 is selected A1 = 3. When A1 = 1 or 2, I want my ActiveX Controls textbox to be white and when A1 = 3, I want the textbox to be yellow. This is code that I came up with but the color of the textbox isn't changing.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

If Sheets(12).Range("A1") = 3 Then
TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
Else: TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 option buttons that change the value of this A1 cell, you can check the option buttons value instead. And then you can either 
a) change the color of the textbox when one of these option buttons is clicked; or 
b) set the text of the textbox, and which will then fire the change event of the textbox.

If option buttons 1 or 2 are selected, then color it yellow, otherwise, color it white. Something like this (note that the white color is *RGB(255, 255, 255)*):

```vbs
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    Sheets(1).Range("A1") = 1
    TextBox1.Text = 1
'    TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    Sheets(1).Range("A1") = 2
    TextBox1.Text = 2
'    TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
    Sheets(1).Range("A1") = 3
    TextBox1.Text = 3
'    TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If OptionButton1.Value Or OptionButton2.Value Then
        TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'yellow
    Else
        TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'white
    End If
End Sub
```